# Open a specified form based on a button in a continuous form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a continuous form with a button for each record, I want that button to open another form with a specified WHERE clause (ID = "123").

**edit**: I figured out that the ID still pulls until I start querying data from another table. So I can use the table where the ID lives but if I add in another table, the TaskID value becomes Null. Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub btnOpenForm_Click()
On Error GoTo btnOpenForm_Click_Err
Dim strWhere As String

'Assigns TaskID from continuous form
strWhere = "[TaskID] = " & Me.[TaskID]    

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDBAFix", , , strWhere

btnOpenForm_Click_Exit:
Exit Sub
btnOpenForm_Click_Err:
MsgBox Error$
Resume btnOpenForm_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please share the recordsource for your existing continuous subform (with the added table). Unless you are doing either a Left or Right join, the original ID field should not have become Null.

Comment: I figured out the issue. I needed to use a Left join. The data was null because the foreign key was 'nulling' the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data from the first table was appearing as null because the tables were linked via foreign key and the 2nd table had no data.

Not sure why it even prevent textfields from appearing but... i'll leave it alone.

Thanks